# Trouble on caching an action when I rewrite a URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, url

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I have an issue on caching when I rewrite a URL in the model using the `to_param` method.

In my User model I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param # Rewrites URL
    "#{self.id}-#{self.name}-#{self.surname}"
  end

  ...
end
```

In the User controller I have:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  caches_action :show

  def show
    ...
  end
end
```

In the Users sweeper I have:

```
class UsersSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe User

  def after_save(user)
    clear_users_cache(user)
  end

  def after_destroy(user)
    clear_users_cache(user)
  end

  def clear_users_cache(user)
    expire_action :controller => :users, :action => :show, :id => user
  end
end
```

Now, when I browse the user show page in the log file I get:

```
Write fragment views/<my_site_name>/users/2-Test_name-Test_surname (0.3ms)
```

When I expire the cache after a change the name or surname in the log file I get

```
Expire fragment views/<my_site_name>/users/2-New_test_name-New_test_surname (0.3ms)
```

*So, since the data is changed, it doesn't expire the cache* because Rails try to expire `2-New_test_name-New_test_surname` and not `2-Test_name-Test_surname`.

**How can I "easly" handle the Rails caching behavior to make it to work?**

---

P.S.: Of course if I don't use the `to_param` method, it works as well.

---

**UPDATED**

I can do something like this

```
caches_action :show, :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| 'users/' + c.params[:id].split('-').first }
```

but I don't think that is a good way to solve things...

Answer (score 0):

Try using a custom path:

> You can set modify the default action cache path by passing a `:cache_path` option. This will be passed directly to `ActionCachePath.path_for`. This is handy for actions with multiple possible routes that should be cached differently. If a block is given, it is called with the current controller instance.

```
caches_action :show, :cache_path => { :project => 1 }
```

Obviously customize to suit your needs. See the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Actions.html) for more info.

Comment: I tryed to do something like ':cache_path => { :project => "#{@user.id}-#{@user.firstname}-#{@user.lastname}" }' and others "experiment" but it doesn't work. Anyway I think that will don't help me because the User name and surname change just before that Rails expires the cache, so it will try to expire '2-New_test_name-New_test_surname' and not '2-Test_name-Test_surname'. Maybe I have to keep\pass someway old User name and surname values.

Comment: I updated the question adding a possible, but not the best, solution.

Comment: Why is the solution you edited your question with not the best? It does exactly what you need to do and uses my answer as a basis.

Comment: Because that solution works ONLY with the 'def to_param "#{self.id}-#{self.name}-#{self.surname}" end' statement, but I would like to have a more "general approach".

Comment: Actually it will work with any string beginning with the ID and either followed immediately by a hyphen and then other text or by nothing at all.